# Match a longer string with a shorter one

Tags: mysql

I have a form where users can search all the entries in a table and i'm having problems with a specific entry.

I'll give an example for a better understanding:

The user can check 5 boxes: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and he checks all the boxes.

If the specific row has the value '1|2|3', my search query won't find it.

Beforehand i get the post variable in php (which is an array) and add '%' before and after every value. In this case: '%1%2%3%4%5%'

My search query:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE string LIKE '%1%2%3%4%5%'
```

In this case, it won't find the row with the value '1|2|3'.
I guess it's normal this way and it works great the other way around but I want to perform a query that matches parts of the original string. In my case '%1%2%3%4%5%' to match '1|2|3'.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance for taking the time.

EDIT: Can i do this without multiple AND, OR operators?

Comment: just as a sidenote: this sounds like havn't normalized your database. you should really consider to so so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change it to this:

```
string LIKE '%1%'
  OR
string LIKE '%2%'
  OR
string LIKE '%3%'
  ...
```

this would solve your problem - but you should really think about [normalizing your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (in this case, store 5 different flags as 1/0 for the five different settings instead of putting them all together in one field).

Comment: I did add separate flags in the beginning but i have 13 checkboxes which would add 13 columns to my db. Now i just use one row with values separated by '|' and then use php explode to display separate values. I thought this would be more efficient than adding 13 columns

Comment: you should really use seperate columns - if there are that much flags, add a lot of columns - not doing this is going to make a lot of other problems in the future and having seperate colums will make queries (especially complex ones) a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

Before you find something sexier and more efficient, you can use:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE string LIKE '%1%' OR string LIKE '%2%' OR string LIKE '%3%' OR string LIKE '%4%' OR string LIKE '%5%'
```

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking on doing this but was looking for a more simple and exact query. I will go with this if I don't find something better.

Answer (score 0):

I would say - dont use like, use substring or some similar function.

Comment: I have never used substring but i'll take a look at it. I'm fairly new to more advanced stuff in mysql. Thank you.